# requirejs + bower, paths and dependencies within bower components

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower, amd

I have done a lot of research but can't find the answer I am looking for, so here goes.

I have a bower component which has its own dependencies:

> /vendor/bower_components/my_module/my_module.js
> /vendor/bower_components/my_module/dependency_1.js
> /vendor/bower_components/my_module/dependency_2.js

Inside of my_module.js, it loads its dependencies using relative paths:

```
define(["./dependency_1", "./dependency_2"], function (dep1, dep2) { ... });
```

But when my requirejs config.paths is set up:

```
paths: {
    my_module: "/vendor/bower_components/my_module/my_module"
}
```

... now the relative paths are relative to the base requirejs path and not the full path for my_module.  I understand why this is happening (because the module id is no longer the full path, but rather the shortened name), I just don't know how to solve it.  I am pretty sure packages is the right direction, I'm just not having any luck.  How should I go about this?  `my_module` is a third party module btw and would rather not edit it.  Thanks.

#### UPDATE - Example uses of code within my application:

Scenario 1 (without `config.paths`):

```
define(["/vendor/bower_components/my_module/my_module"], function(myModule) {
    // This works.  No issues here.
    // The reason this works is because the module ID for myModule is:
    // "/vendor/bower_components/my_module/my_module"
    // Therefore, the relative paths "./dependency_1" and "./dependency_2"
    // are resolved against that module ID.
});
```

Scenario 2 - now my_module is defined in config.paths (see above):

```
define(["my_module"], function(myModule) {
    // Error, cannot load files dependency_1.js or dependency_2.js
    // This is because relative paths are resolved against a module's ID.
    // Now the module ID is "my_module", not "/vendor/bower_components/my_module/my_module"
    // As such, the paths for ./dependency_1 and ./dependency_2 are resolved against "/"
});
```

Unfortunately (or not?) this happens by design: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes-relative-names.  We should be able to use packages to resolve this.  I'm just wondering if anybody has any knowledge of how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, my English maybe bad but... what is the question? I just try to read it several times but no clues about what is your problem. Like is it not run? or you have encounted any problem?

Comment: I updated my question.  Let me know if that makes more sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get so far with your question. You can do what you want (or not?) with these configurations:

```
require.config({
    packages: [
        {
            name: "myModule"
            location: '/vendor/bower_components/my_module/',
            main: "my_module"
        }
        // [name option] can be anything you want
        // [main option] pointing to your main js file of the package
        // if you rename your mymodule.js to main.js you no longer need to config the [main option]
    ]
});
```

and in your my_module.js

```
define(["./dependency_1", "./dependency_2"], function (dep1, dep2) {
  // ...
});
```

And you can call your my_module.js like this.

```
define(["myModule"], function(myModule) {
    // ...
});
```

For further info you can check out this link [Common-config#packages](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/Common-Config#packages-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.  I will test it monday if I have time.  The main issue with this is I can't update the code for my_module.  I should have named it `someone_elses_module` in my examples, but that was too wordy.  Your solution seems right on track though.

Comment: hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks a bunch.  Worth noting that `my_module` is a standard AMD library and not a CommonJS library.  The requirejs docs imply that packages should be used for CommonJS libraries... but it can be used for anything.